# Create an array of objects from another array grouping duplicates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, reduce

I need to re-organize an array of objects (from a database) into different groups according to one of the attributes of objects. To make it clearer, let's take the following example:

The ORM (Sequelize) returns the following array object:

```
[
  {
    id: 182,
    employeeId: 'a',
    skillId: 207,   
    score: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 512,
    employeeId: 'a',
    skillId: 212,
    score: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 908,
    employeeId: 'b',
    skillId: 134,
    score: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 876,
    employeeId: 'c',
    skillId: 212,
    score: 3,
  },
]
```

I need to re-categorize the object grouping the entries by employeeId. Like this:

```
[
  {
    employeeId: 'a',
    skills: 
           [
             { skillId: 203, score: 3},
             { skillId: 212, score: 4}
           ]
  },
  {
    employeeId: 'b',
    skills: 
           [
             { skillId: 134, score: 2}
           ]
   },
   {
    employeeId: 'c',
    skills: 
           [
             { skillId: 212, score: 3}
           ]
   }
]
```

It didn't look hard at first but I'm hitting a roadblock, I already tried using reduce, forEarch and map but I only got to make an array of employeeIds, can't really get to include the skills array in each object of the array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const result = [
  {
    id: 182,
    employeeId: 'a',
    skillId: 207,   
    score: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 512,
    employeeId: 'a',
    skillId: 212,
    score: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 908,
    employeeId: 'b',
    skillId: 134,
    score: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 876,
    employeeId: 'c',
    skillId: 212,
    score: 3,
  },
]



const tempObj = result.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.employeeId in acc) {
        acc[curr.employeeId].push({
            skillId: curr.skillId,
            score: curr.score
        })
    } else {
        acc[curr.employeeId] = [{
            skillId: curr.skillId,
            score: curr.score
        }]
    }
    return acc
}, {})

const reorganized = Object.keys(tempObj).map(key => ({
    employeeId: key,
    skills: tempObj[key]
}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(reorganized, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses classes to build up the employee object and could be easily extended in the future.

```js
const input = [{
    id: 182,
    employeeId: 'a',
    skillId: 207,
    score: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 512,
    employeeId: 'a',
    skillId: 212,
    score: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 908,
    employeeId: 'b',
    skillId: 134,
    score: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 876,
    employeeId: 'c',
    skillId: 212,
    score: 3,
  },
];

const employeeMap = {};

class Skill {
  constructor({
    skillId,
    score
  }) {
    this.skillId = skillId;
    this.score = score;
  }
}

class Employee {
  constructor(rawEmployee) {
    this.employeeId = rawEmployee.employeeId;
    this.skills = [];
  }
  addSkill(rawEmployee) {
    this.skills.push(new Skill(rawEmployee));
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  const rawEmployee = input[i];
  let employee = employeeMap[rawEmployee.employeeId];
  if (!employee) {
    employee = new Employee(rawEmployee);
    employeeMap[employee.employeeId] = employee;
  }
  if (employee) {
    employee.addSkill(rawEmployee);
  }
}

const employeeArray = [];

for (let key in employeeMap) {
  employeeArray.push(employeeMap[key]);
}

console.log(employeeArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(employeeArray));
```